# Mocking ICollection property in entity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm performing some unit tests on my entities and I've had a bit of a mental block mocking a property. Take the following entities:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int MaxBobs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method on `Teacher` called `AddStudent` which first checks whether a teacher has too many students called Bob assigned. If so, then I raise a custom exception saying too many bobs. The method looks like this:

```
public void AddStudent(Student student)
{
    if (student.Name.Equals("Bob"))
    {
        if (this.Students.Count(s => s.Name.Equals("Bob")) >= this.MaxBobs)
        {
            throw new TooManyBobsException("Too many Bobs!!");
        }
    }

    this.Students.Add(student);
}
```

I'd like to unit test this using **Moq** mocks - specifically I want to mock the `.Count` method of `Teacher.Students` where I can pass it any expression and it'll return a number suggesting there are currently 10 Bobs assigned to that teacher. I'm setting it up like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(TooManyBobsException))]
public void Can_not_add_too_many_bobs()
{
    Mock<ICollection<Student>> students = new Mock<ICollection<Student>>();
    students.Setup(s => s.Count(It.IsAny<Func<Student, bool>>()).Returns(10);

    Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
    teacher.MaxBobs = 1;

    // set the collection to the Mock - I think this is where I'm going wrong
    teacher.Students = students.Object; 

    // the next line should raise an exception because there can be only one
    // Bob, yet my mocked collection says there are 10
    teacher.AddStudent(new Student() { Name = "Bob" });
}
```

I'm expecting my custom exception, but what I'm actually getting is `System.NotSupportedException` which infers that the `.Count` method of `ICollection` isn't virtual and therefore cannot be mocked. How do I mock this particular function?

Any help always appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't mock the `Count` method you are using, because it is an extension method. It isn't a method defined on `ICollection<T>`.
The simplest solution would be to simply assign a list with 10 bobs to the `Students` property:

```
teacher.Students = Enumerable.Repeat(new Student { Name = "Bob" }, 10)
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: As a side note, moles or fakes frameworks allow mocking of extension methods.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth of course! I knew it was something like that, working as intended now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to mock the collection when you can simply verify whether the exception was thrown using the real collection rather than a mock. As you're using MsTest rather than NUnit, you can't simply add an ExpectedException attribute to verify that the exception is thrown, but you can do something like the following:

```
Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
teacher.MaxBobs = 1;

teacher.Students = new Collection<Student>(); 

var hasTooManyBobs = false;
try 
{
    teacher.AddStudent(new Student() { Name = "Bob" });
    teacher.AddStudent(new Student() { Name = "Bob" });
}
catch(TooManyBobsException)
{
    hasTooManyBobs = true;
}

Assert.IsFalse(hasTooManyBobs);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Assert.IsTrue(hasTooManyBobs);`?

Comment: MSTest supports the [ExpectedException attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx). No need for a try-catch block.